# How to end a session in Selenium and start a new one?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to quit the browser session and start a new one when I hit an exception. Normally I wouldn't do this, but in this specific case it seems to make sense.

```
def get_info(url):
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        #get page data
        business_type_x = '//*[@id="page-desc"]/div[2]/div'
        business_type = browser.find_element_by_xpath(business_type_x).text
        print(business_type)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        #new session
        browser.quit()
        return get_info(url)
```

This results in this error: `http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response`

I expected it to open a new browser window with a new session. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can not just open a new browser after quitting you need to create the browser again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the driver object again once you quite that. Initiate the driver in the `get_info` method again.

You can replace `webdriver.Firefox()` with whatever driver you are using.

```
def get_info(url):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        #get page data
        business_type_x = '//*[@id="page-desc"]/div[2]/div'
        business_type = browser.find_element_by_xpath(business_type_x).text
        print(business_type)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        #new session
        browser.quit()
        return get_info(url)
```

You can also use `close` method instead of `quit`. So that you do not have to recreate the browser object.

```
def get_info(url):
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        #get page data
        business_type_x = '//*[@id="page-desc"]/div[2]/div'
        business_type = browser.find_element_by_xpath(business_type_x).text
        print(business_type)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        #new session
        browser.close()
        return get_info(url)
```

difference between quit and close can be found in the documentation as well.

[quit](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver.quit)

[close](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.close)

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* instance i.e. `browser` was unable to communicate with the *Browsing Context* i.e. the *Web Browsing* session.

If your usecase is to keep on trying to invoke the same *url* in a loop till the desired element is getting located you can use the following solution:

```
def get_info(url):
    while True:
        browser.get(url)
        try:
            #get page data
            business_type_x = '//*[@id="page-desc"]/div[2]/div'
            business_type = browser.find_element_by_xpath(business_type_x).text
            print(business_type)
            break
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```