# How to restart Selenium browser after quit?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to quit and then restart a new browser session with Selenium when encountering a captcha, and I'm not sure yet why the code below isn't working.

It quits the existing driver, but after recursion `browser.get()` results in this error: `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused`

Thanks in advance for any advice. I've included only the most relevant parts of the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
path_to_chromedriver = '/Users/Myname/Desktop/a/chromedriver 2'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
#options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
#options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36'}

def get_page_info(url, browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)):
    browser.get(url)
    try:
        body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        if "been denied because we believe" in body.text:
            print("going to new session...")
            browser.quit()
            human(4,6) #time delay
            return winery_info(url)
```

Edit: I normally wouldn't use this tactic to get around a captcha, but in my use case this makes sense.

Comment: That was exactly the reason I didn't wanted you to call [`get_info(url)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196372/how-to-end-a-session-in-selenium-and-start-a-new-one/60196929#60196929) recursively and adapt **continue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the driver.delete_all_cookies() method instead of closing browser and reopening it

edit : maybe the site block your ip adress i suggest you to use tor to change ip automatically i will give you this

```
import os
import time

os.system("killall tor")
os.system("tor &")
time.sleep(5)

#init driver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1")
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", int("9050"))
fp.update_preferences()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp) 

browser.get(...)
...
...
if captcha:
    os.system("killall tor")
    os.system("tor &")
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.get(...)
    # this will change your ip adress
    # You can also configure tor to change ip every 10 seconds by changing torrc file
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it still gives me a captcha